# Have the at command return the job id of the task just submitted

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scheduled-tasks, at

Is it possible to have the **at** command return somehow the job id it just submitted when used from within a script? (kind of like $? retrieves the last exit code or $$/$! retrieve the PID of the command just executed).

Comment: When I run `echo "touch foo" | at now`, I get e.g. `job 3 at Thu Dec 15 17:14:52 2011` as output — you don't? Likewise inside a script, it writes to standard output, from where it can be parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the job you want to run is in a file called `test.sh`, the following will return the id:

```
 $ at now -f test.sh 2>&1 | awk '/job/ {print $2}'
 8
```

The `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout so you can manipulate it. The `awk` returns the second field in the line that has the word "job" in it, which is the line that contains the job id.

So it get it into a variable, you can do:

```
$ TEST=`at now -f test.sh 2>&1 | awk '/job/ {print $2}'`
$ echo $TEST
9
```